# Mysql - Split data into div

Tags: php, mysql, html, split

I have a table called "Names", it contains about 400 inputs.
I want for every 50 names to be in one div.

```
<div id="1">name1, name2, ... name50</div>
<div id="2">name51,name52, ... name100</div> and so on ...
```

Any help?

Comment: Show what you've written so far, and we can help fix it. We're not here to do your job for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily achieved using the following script (hopefully I skipped the syntax errors):

```
<?php
    //Get the names
    $names_res = mysql_query("SELECT names FROM Names");

    //Set a counter
    $counter = 0;

    //Loop over the names
    while( $name_arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($names_res) )

        //Let's see now...
        if( ($counter % 50 == 0) || $counter == 0  ) 
            echo '<div id="', ( ($counter == 0)? 1 : ($counter/50)+1 ) , '">';    

        //Output the name
        echo $name_array['name'] , ( ($counter % 49 === 0 )? '' : ', ' );

        //Close the div if neccesary
        if( ($counter % 49 == 0) || $counter == 0 ) echo '</div>';

        //Yes, we do want to increment it
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

Good luck!

Comment: The output is not correct, it gives each name in one div. It should be each 50 names in one div.

Comment: Oh fork, I forgot to add the `$i++` at the end of my while-loop - fixed in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should at least be a good start:

```
for ($n = 0; $n< 140; $n++) {
    $names[] = 'name'.$n;
}

$n = 0;
$div = 0;
foreach ($names as $name) {
    if ($n%50 == 0) {
        $div++;
        echo '<div id="'.$div.'">';
    }
    echo $name . ', ';
    if ($n%50 == 49) {
        echo '</div>';
    }
    $n++;
}
echo '</div>';
```